# How do I restart nginx from a python script?

Tags: python, nginx

I can use `"nginx -s reload"` command to restart nginx on the shell.
But, when I use `os.system("nginx -s reload")` command, It appears error.

`/usr/local/bin/nginx: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

For this error. I already install pcre. Is there some magic problems.

Answer (score 4):

For running such commands in python scripts it's better to use [subprocess library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

try this code instead of yours:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('whatever command you want to run it in terminal', shell=True)
```

Be lucky

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hello I recommend that you first send this validation before sending the reset so you avoid headaches

```
reinicioNGINX = subprocess.getoutput(['nginx -t'])
```

if 'nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok' in reinicioNGINX:

_command_restart

else:

_command_avoid_restart